# Concatenation of two lists in a third one

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to write a predicate **concat/3** with header *concat(whole, part1, part2)* that succeeds if *part1* and *part2* are two not-empty subsequences which when concatenated form the sequence *whole*. For example
`concat(A, [12, a, z],[1, 2, 3, 4])`  answers with
`A = [12, a, z, 1, 2, 3, 4]`. I've looked at `append/3`, but when I change it putting the whole as the first parameter it fails. This is my code so far:

```
concat(List, [], List).
concat([Head|Rest], [Head|Tail], List) :-
    concat(Rest, Tail, List).
```

When I ask `concat(A,[a],[b]).` it answers "no"

Comment: Where are you stuck? Please show some code...

Comment: Your example doesn't match the specification.

Comment: Take a look at the source code for [`append/3`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/lists.pl?show=src#append/3) (a badly named predicate which should have been called concatenation/3)

Comment: You just take a look at append/3. It is exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: If you "don't know how to get started", you *can't* "know it's pretty simple".

Comment: I've fixed my error with the example and added some code that doesn't work. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look to the answer in [Make a list as the consecutive union of two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67537284/make-a-list-as-the-consecutive-union-of-two-lists).
Basically, you need to check that both are non-empty lists and then append(Res, L1, L2).