# Make a list as the consecutive union of two lists

Tags: prolog

i'm trying to do a predicate **unionlist(union,list1,list2)**, where **"union"** is the list formed as the union of **"list1"** and **"list2"**. This lists cannot be empty.

For example:

```
unionlist(L,[a,b],[c,d]).
```

Output should be:

```
L=[a,b,c,d]
```

Another example:

```
unionlist([a,b],L1,L2).
```

Output should be:

```
L1=[a],L2=[b] ;
no
```

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check if both are non-empty after appending them,

```
unionlist(Union, L1, L2) :-
    append(L1, L2, Union),
    length(L1, Len1),
    Len1 > 0,
    length(L2, Len2),
    Len2 > 0.
```

**[EDIT]** - append in the beginning, so that the predicate can be used in reverse

Comment: You can check the edit. It should work now.